# Default display of axes in Matlab Gui

Tags: matlab

I tried using axes for displaying images in Gui.But, before displaying any images, the axes is shown with a plot figure while running the GUI, something like below.

[image]

You can see the default axes being displayed. Is there a way to display the axes in running GUI without displaying these plot figures? So that when the image is not displayed in the axes, nothing is displayed. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

I have used 9 axes here, thus the long trail of y axis.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use

```
axis off
```

To remove the axes from the empty plots. Then use

```
axis on
```

When you actually plot something to bring them back.

Best,